# SQL : Decode with less than operator complex

Tags: sql

I want to select only rows which have GAS < 0.9 and oil < 0.9 from the following working query.

THe below query works fine but i am not able to put in a check to select only when GAS < 0.9 and oil < 0.9 value, as I already using groupby ; I am not sure whats the best way to get this result.

```
SELECT
         rf.DAYTIME,
         GEO_FIELD_CODE,
         f.NAME,
         ROUND(decode(THEOR_GAS_RATE_SM3, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL,ABS(ALLOC_GAS_VOL_SM3/THEOR_GAS_RATE_SM3)),3) AS GAS,
         ROUND(decode(THEOR_NET_OIL_RATE_STM3, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL,ABS(ALLOC_NET_OIL_VOL_STM3/THEOR_NET_OIL_RATE_STM3)),3) AS OIL
FROM (SELECT 
         DAYTIME,
         GEO_FIELD_CODE,
         SUM(THEOR_GAS_RATE_SM3) AS THEOR_GAS_RATE_SM3,
         SUM(ALLOC_GAS_VOL_SM3) AS ALLOC_GAS_VOL_SM3,
         SUM(THEOR_NET_OIL_RATE_STM3) AS THEOR_NET_OIL_RATE_STM3,
         SUM(ALLOC_NET_OIL_VOL_STM3) AS ALLOC_NET_OIL_VOL_STM3
    FROM XYZ
   WHERE DAYTIME >= TO_DATE ('2013-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
    GROUP BY DAYTIME, GEO_FIELD_CODE
ORDER BY GEO_FIELD_CODE, DAYTIME) rf, ECKERNEL_HALE.OV_FIELD f
WHERE rf.GEO_FIELD_CODE = f.CODE
```

any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I see two different ways to solve it. You can use the expressions that are used to calculate the values in the condition:

```
WHERE
  rf.GEO_FIELD_CODE = f.CODE AND
  ROUND(decode(THEOR_GAS_RATE_SM3, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL,ABS(ALLOC_GAS_VOL_SM3/THEOR_GAS_RATE_SM3)),3) < 0.9 AND
  ROUND(decode(THEOR_NET_OIL_RATE_STM3, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL,ABS(ALLOC_NET_OIL_VOL_STM3/THEOR_NET_OIL_RATE_STM3)),3) < 0.9
```

The query planner should be clever enough to see that it's the same expressions, so that they are not actually calculated twice. The other alternative is to wrap your entire query in another query so that you can access the results of the expressions:

```
SELECT DAYTIME, GEO_FIELD_CODE, NAME, GAS, OIL
FROM (
  ... your current query goes here
) x
WHERE GAS < 0.9 AND OIL < 0.9
```

Comment: Thanks , I got the results both ways. The first one takes a bit of time, but I need to verify the results to make sure they are not calculated twice. The second method is the last solution which I was hoping, will probably stick with that to be safe. Thanks for the advice...much appreciated.